# How can I fix a package does not exist error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am wondering what I can do to get rid of this error : java:4: error: package professorCode does not exist.
I have attached my code and I am using packages that have already been given to me to implement. I am confused because I have the professor code packages downloaded.  My code is here below:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import professorCode.AbstractFileMonitor;
import professorCode.FileTextReader;
import professorCode.FileTextWriter;

public class FileManager extends AbstractFileMonitor implements FileTextReader, FileTextWriter {
    String filePath;

    public FileManager(String filePath) {
        super(filePath);
    }

    public String readText(String path) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
    }

    public Set<String> getAllLines(String path) throws IOException {
        String allText = this.readText(path);
        Set<String> stringArrayList = new HashSet();
        String[] var4 = allText.split("\n");
        int var5 = var4.length;

        for(int var6 = 0; var6 < var5; ++var6) {
            String line = var4[var6];
            stringArrayList.add(line.trim());
        }

        return stringArrayList;
    }

    public String getLastLine(String path) throws IOException {
        String[] segments = this.readText(path).split("\n");

        for(int i = segments.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
            String clean = segments[i].trim();
            if (!clean.isEmpty()) {
                return clean;
            }
        }

        return "";
    }

    public void writeToFile(String string, String path) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        String clean = string.trim();
        if (clean.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true));
            out.write(string + "\n");
            out.close();
        }
    }

    public void setFilePath(String path) {
        if (path != null && !path.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.filePath = path;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public String getFilePath() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (this.filePath == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        } else {
            return this.filePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: They may be downloaded, but are they one the classpath?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency.

Comment: Just a note: the package names do not follow the Java Naming Conventions, while they should. Package names are always in lowercaseonly.